# Laravel Livewire: Bootstrap Tooltip doesn't show up after livewire validation

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-5, laravel-livewire

I recently found my bootstrap 5 tooltips stopped working after I use livewire to validate or do any certain task.
Whenever livewire sends the data to the server to validate or change something, my tooltips come like the normal title tag.

**Before Validation:**
[image: Before Validation]

**After Validation:**
[[image: After Validation2]

**Blade HTML:**

```
<abbr data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
      data-bs-placement="left"
      data-bs-html="true"
      title="{!! trans('mmhg_fullform') !!}">
     {!! trans('mmhg') !!}
</abbr>
```

Not really sure why is this happening, I also have a code in js

```
$('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Do we have to make certain changes anywhere to use bootstrap tooltips in livewire components?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had trouble with the other answer posted here, it seems simply calling `.tooltip()` again doesn't work consistently with Livewire, I suspect due to DOM diffing issues.

This was the solution I found:

**For Bootstrap 4**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // ...

  // Enable Bootstrap tooltips on page load
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  // Ensure Livewire updates re-instantiate tooltips
  if (typeof window.Livewire !== 'undefined') {
    window.Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose').tooltip();
    });
  }

});
```

**For Bootstrap 5**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // ...

  // Enable Bootstrap tooltips on page load
  $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

  // Ensure Livewire updates re-instantiate tooltips
  if (typeof window.Livewire !== 'undefined') {
    window.Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {
        $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose').tooltip();
    });
  }

});
```

This checks to ensure Livewire is loaded on the page first, so you can include it in your normal JS even if you only use Livewire on certain pages.

Calling `tooltip('dispose')` first will allow all new and existing tooltips on the page to be re-instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

try this, to maintain hydrated that element in blade re-render...I don't tested it, just try it.

in blade script section

```
window.livewire.on('tooltipHydrate', () => {
    $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

in component

```
public function hydrate()
{
  $this->emit('tooltipHydrate');
}
```

Comment: I tried this, this worked but only once. As in when I try to validate first time it works fine, before validation it works fine but when I try to do it again it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

This work for
Bootstrap 5.x + Laravel 10.x + Livewire 3.x

```
<button wire:click = "$dispatch('askForChangeStatus', {state:{{ $User->state }}})" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-original-title="@t('Disable Account')"  class="btn btn-warning-light btn-wave waves-effect waves-light p-2">
    <i class="bi bi-slash-circle fs-5 fw-semibold d-flex m-auto"></i>
</button>
```

The key in my case was to use `data-bs-original-title` instead of the original `title` attribute. No js code require.